# "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта" при чтении конфигурационного файла. c#

Tags: c#, config, configuration

Я пытаюсь открыть свой config файл и прочитать от туда значение (ключа или значения не важно) и получаю ошибку "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта". Что я делаю не так?
Код с формы:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"C:\MyApp.config"; 
        Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        string c = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Login"].Key;
        textBox1.Text = c;
    }
```

Код config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Login" value="" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Пожалуйста подскажите.

Comment: В какой строке конкретно ошибка?

Comment: `<appSetting>` ===> `<appSettings>`?

Comment: string c = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Login"].Key;
System.NullReferenceException на этой выдает вот это.

Comment: Я вообще пытаюсь открыть свой конфиг файл прочитать от туда значения, в идеале еще их иметь возможность изменять. И при закрытии этой формы и открытии новой, что бы был доступ к этому файлу и с других форм, и они так же могли менять его.

Comment: У вас опечатка в xml файле

Comment: Да спасибо заметила, исправила <appSetting> ===> <appSettings>, но ошибка та же.

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести, у меня ваш код работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Спасибо большое всем за ответы!** Но я смогла найти сама ответ на свой вопрос.
Данный выше код работает прекрасно если создавать не config файл, а xml и тогда все прекрасно редактируется и изменяется. Еще один не мало важный факт.. не знаю почему, но программно **нельзя сохранить пустую строку!**  Что меня удивило, ведь и в config и в xml можно прописать пустое значение и все будет работать...
(PS: Данный код xml можно прописать и в конфиг) Так же обращение к Xml файлу исправило ошибку заданную мной в вопросе.

Прикладываю  свой код решения. Вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится...

Код в Form1:

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text.Length > 0 && textBox3.Text.Length > 0 && st == true && checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"C:\Project\Visual Studio\Agenstvo\XMLFile1.xml";
            Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Login"].Value = " ";
            configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Password"].Value = " ";
            configuration.AppSettings.Settings["check"].Value = Convert.ToString(checkBox1.Checked);
            configuration.Save();
        }
```

Код в Form2:

```
 private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (avt != true)
        {
            ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"C:\Project\Visual Studio\Agenstvo\XMLFile1.xml";
            Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Login"].Value = " ";
            configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Password"].Value = " ";
            configuration.AppSettings.Settings["check"].Value = Convert.ToString(false);
            configuration.Save();
        }
    }
```

Xml файл код:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
     <appSettings>
   <add key="Login" value="" />
   <add key="Password" value="" />
   <add key="check" value="False" />
     </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а вопрос из этого «ответа», пожалуйста, удалите.

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе без разницы где будет лежать твой конфиг файл. То лучше использовать встроенный конфиг, который находится в твоем проекте. Тогда можно будет вместо всего кода в **Form1_Load** написать просто

```
 textBox1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Login"];
```

Если же тебе надо именно использовать сторонний конфиг, то тебе надо будет прописать в конфиге, который находится у тебя в проекте, следующее

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings file="C:\Users\MyApp.config">
    <add key="SomeValue" value="value" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Основной трюк здесь в строчке `file="C:\Users\MyApp.config"` здесь ты указываешь путь к дополнительному конфигу из которого будут вычитываться данные. Так же тебе будут доступны данные из стандартного конфига приложения. Произойдет мерж двух конфигов.
Второй конфиг должен будет иметь следующую структуру

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="Login" value="aaaaaaa" />
</appSettings>
```

И тогда ты можешь использовать внешний конфиг к доплнению к стандартному и так же просто написать:

```
textBox1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Login"];
```

Если есть какие-то вопросы, то могу пояснить

Comment: Хороший ответ, информативный, но к сожалению он никак не помогает решить проблему, обозначенную в вопросе.

Comment: Да, ответ полезный, но к сожалению не подходит для моего решения( 
Мне так же нужно иметь возможность изменять файл с приложения. Стандартный файл настроек изменять нельзя из приложения.. Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: @Sherlock_201 Я увидел, что уже проблема решена. Но, отвечая на вопрос, конфиг можно менять из приложения даже во время выполнения. Вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819544/changing-app-settings-during-run-time)